# Which Atzei Chayim does the Yad go on

Tags: sefer-torah

When dressing the Torah for it's return to the Ark, does the Yad (chain) go around a particular Atz Chayim? If so, right or left when facing the Torah?

Comment: In our shul, we generally put it over both, and if it is one with a long chain and/or a short sefer then we actually put it over the back first and loop it back through the middle to the front so it doesn't hang too low